# Make an object always the same shape as another but thicker?

Tags: modeling

I'm trying to make an eyelid. I've been messing around with rotations and lattices but with the weird shape the eye has to be with this character I can't find a way to rotate the lid while keeping it close to the eye.

So what I'm wondering, is there any modifier I can use that will make the eyelid object always the exact same shape as the eye but just a little bigger? So that when I rotate it, the faces automatically shrink down to touch the eye.

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try the *Displace Modifier* for static meshes, with no texture assigned it will simply offset a mesh for the specified distance.

[image]

It looks like you need something different though, so try the *Shrinkwrap Modifier*, with an *Offset* value.

[image]

Comment: I'm intrigued! I guess it won't be relevant after EEVEE, but how are you getting that fresnel-looking render in OpenGL?

Comment: Even though it is very bare, viewport material preview for Cycles has supported fresnel and layer weight nodes in OpenGL for a while now.

Answer (score 1):

You could make the eyelid single layer, making it conform quite closely to the eyeball, (possibly by duplicating the mesh from part of the eyeball,) and then assign it a Shrinkwrap modifier with the eyeball as target, (probably set to 'Nearest Surface Point'), followed by a Solidify modifier to give it thickness.

If you want the lid to remain single layer, a small offset can keep it above the surface, but tweaking is a little more tricky

Sometimes having part of your subdivision above the Shrinkwrap can help give a better resolution to the wrap.